# How can you remove a Facebook “Community” Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-privacy

A while back, my friend put my name as the name of the university he attended on Facebook as a joke. Facebook automatically created a community page for the 'university' but he doesn't see a delete option. As I have quite a unique name, finding any associated pages about me using Google is/would be very easy. I'm somewhat paranoid about everything I put on the Internet, opting to use pseudonyms nearly everywhere so there aren't many publicly idenitfiable records of anything I've said online.

As a side note, I've come to the belief there are *probably* at least a few unscrupulous private entities that scrape Facebook, and any other sites that use identifiable information to build profiles of you using anything and everything they can get. The information they have may or may not be publicly accesible. As an example, I had discovered that because I used my real name on Facebook, I was on a site that scraped Facebook data between 2007-2010 - but this page about me only appeared **recently** (within the past few months). To the best of my knowledge, my Facebook profile at the time was set to private (maybe posts only, I'm not sure), though this site has my birthday, friends list and pages I liked back in 2010. Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to delete this information.

Anyway, given my above reasoning and because I am privacy conscious and like to keep a low profile on the Internet, and also because the 'university' page on Facebook shows up on Google search and is therefore visible elsewhere, is there a way my friend/myself could get ownership of the community page and delete it? If not should I report the page? Would reporting it affect my friend if he could be linked as the creator of the page?